# Are DDD Aggregates classes or are they implicit?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I mean, is there any `PersonAggregate` class? I understand it doesn't exist. I only have an entity acting as aggregate root. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

> I only have an entity acting as aggregate root. Is it correct?

That's correct.

The *aggregate* is implicit - it's the boundary that separates two disjoint sets of state that can be modified independently of each other.  Equivalently, the aggregate is a graph of business state within a model that can be modified without consulting state outside the graph, and vice versa.

The *aggregate root* is explicit.  That's the single entity in the graph that is exposed - which is to say that it serves as the entry point through which all modifications to the graph must pass.

Hypothetically, you could implement an aggregate that has two different exposed entities that can each execute commands to modify the state; Evans introduced the notion of a single aggregate root because multiple entry points is difficult to get correct.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen both solutions used in projects, but most often people do *not* use this suffix.

One interesting solution for this is make aggregate classes public and non-aggregate classes package(default). You'd see directly from your IDE which classes have which visibility and you can determine easily where is an aggregate. Additionally non-public class cannot be used outside package which is an original intent.

Comment: So, my aggregate root will probably be inside my entities folder and I'll know it's an aggregate root only looking at the code. Right?

Comment: Please check updated part about public/non-public classes

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is an Aggregate Root is an Entity but an Entity might not be an Aggregate Root. Therefore, I view 'Aggregate Root' as more of a [stereotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_(UML)).

Answer (score 0):

Not in domain-driven design. That would be exposing technological jargon, essentially implementation detail, to the domain experts